# Discord.py - edit a message the bot has sent

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i would like to edit an embed that I already sent using my bot.
I know that you can edit messages, but how is the case with an embed? I just want to be able to edit the text, not title.

I thought something about this: -editembed [ID] [newtext], I started a bit but I fail at the point when I want to edit the existing message...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a new embed to the edit function as a keyword argument:

```py
my_embed = Embed(title="My title", description="My description here")
message.edit(embed=my_embed)
```

You could probably figure it out yourself by reading the documentation.
Read more at: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit